# How can I scaffold with multiple schemas and particular table?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, devart

I have two schemas Bob and Bill.
I want to scaffold with schema Bob all tables and with schema Bill only View_Otf table.

If I use the following code, I get an empty DbContext:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=something)(PORT=1533)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=otherthing)));User ID=Bob;Password=anotherthing" Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EFCore -o Models -t Bill.View_Otf --schema Bob
```

If I use `--schema Bob --schema Bill` I get all tables from both schemas and I don't need that.

How can I get all the tables from schema Bob and the table Bill.View_Otf?

Thank you!

Comment: You will have to list all tables individually. Or you can try EF Core Power Tools, which has a UI for it.

Comment: Bob schema has many tables, so I'll try EF Core Power Tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to list all tables individually. Or you can try EF Core Power Tools, which has a UI for it.

Answer (score 0):

With [Devart dotConnect for Oracle Professional](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/), you can choose tables from several schemas using Entity Developer. Create Devart EF Core Model (*.efml) and select "Show all users" in Create Model Wizard (Database-First) or press the "Show All Objects" in Database Explorer to see objects from different schemas.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple schema

```
Scaffold-DbContext "<connection string>"
    -Schemas dbo, admin
```

for specific table and schema

```
Scaffold-DbContext "<connection string>"
     -Schemas bob
     -Tables Bill.View_Otf
```